# using google chrome Pepper API to access Win32 API

Tags: google-chrome, winapi, google-chrome-extension

I have to write a google chrome extension/plugin that has to send out events to a win32 service when certain websites are accessed.
1. Is Pepper API/Native Client the right approach to do this?
2. If I can use Pepper API, is it possible to access the Win32 named pipes to send information to the win32 process? If not, is there an alternate approach available to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

Pepper is by the very definition a sandbox, and supposed to be cross-platform. Without knowing anything about it, I would guess that the answer is "no".

> Native Client is a sandbox for running compiled C and C++ code in the browser efficiently and securely, independent of the user’s operating system.

From within an extension, the right approach would be [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging).

The idea is to have a native application ("host") that Chrome can invoke on demand and communicate with. It can serve as a proxy for your calls.

For more information, look around the linked documentation and [chrome-native-messaging](/questions/tagged/chrome-native-messaging) here on SO.